# Removing a node from an XML in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml

I have XML that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Example!</body>
</note>
</inspect>
```

I used Builder, and for some reason it added the `<inspect>` node at the end. How can I remove ?

Comment: That's not XML, XML would have an opening `<inspect>` tag somewhere.

Comment: For parsing and manipulating XML, you're looking for `Nokogiri`.

Comment: As @muistooshort says, your XML is malformed because you can't have a closing `</inspect>` without an opening one. Please confirm whether this is an opening one, or whether the closing `</inspect>` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys... I forgot to explain that I was using builder and it added that node at the end for some reason. Will edit the question.

Comment: For why `</inspect>` is in the XML generated in builder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971225/why-does-ruby-builderxmlmarkup-add-inspect-tag-to-xml

Answer (score 2):

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
xml = <<-EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<inspect>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Example!</body>
</note>
</inspect>
EOF

require 'nokogiri'
tree = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
tree.at_xpath('inspect').replace(tree.at_xpath('inspect/note'))
puts tree.to_s
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Example!</body>
</note>
```

**NOTE**: The original XML does not contain `<inspect>`. I added `<inspect>`.